# react-router vs react-router-dom, when to use one or the other?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Both have Route, Link, etc. When to use one or the other? I'm really confused on where to use each one. Server side? Client side?

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/

In some examples you need to pass the history, in others not. What to do?

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
```

vs

```
<Router>
```

It's really confusing on when to use one or the other, any help appreciated.

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: @RobertColumbia how does that meta.stackoverflow post apply here? Venryx did not ask a "Can someone help me?" question.

Comment: Please check out the link for an additional reference - (readme.md) https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/packages/react-router

Answer (score 332, accepted):

**react-router** contains all the common components between **react-router-dom** and **react-router-native**. When should you use one over the other? If you're on the web then **react-router-dom** should have everything you need as it also exports the common components you'll need. If you're using React Native, **react-router-native** should have everything you need for the same reason. So you'll probably never have to import anything directly from **react-router**. As far as when you use

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
```

vs

```
<Router>
```

In RRv4 you won't need to pass down browserHistory, that was just for previous versions of the router.

If you're still confused, you can check out the details on each package [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages)

Comment: shall we remove react-router from project or it affects react-router-dom?? is that react-router package is mandatory to work with react-router-dom?

Comment: @snAtchnAren It's not mandatory. You should never need the "react-router" package if you've already installed "react-router-dom".

Comment: If I use react-router-dom over react-router, will it decrease the size of my bundle?

Comment: Please check out the link for an additional reference - https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/packages/react-router . (readme.md)

Answer (score 63):

react-router-dom is a `react-router` plus:

- `<BrowserRouter>` which is
  `<Router history={browserNativeHistoryApiWrapper}/>`

  proof: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/BrowserRouter.js
- some Link improvements for browser

  proof: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js
- and with `<NavLink>` — wrapper that knows if it's "active" or not

  proof: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/NavLink.js

Comment: The top answer here "react-router contains all the common components between react-router-dom and react-router-native." and then this answer "react-router-dom is a react-router plus:" so which is it? I'm no expert but it seems like it's still confusing for everyone. When I try Redirect with RR-dom my app fails to compile, in contradiction to the answers here. I need them both in a web-app?

Answer (score 33):

Just use `react-router-dom` - `react-router-dom` re-exports all of `react-router`. The link on GitHub answer ([what's the diff between `react-router-dom` & `react-router`?](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4648)).

Answer (score 16):

> In v4, react-router exports the core components and functions.
> react-router-dom exports DOM-aware components, like `<Link>` ( which
> renders `<a>`) and  (which interacts with the browser's
> window.history ).
>
> `react-router-dom` re-exports all of react-router's exports, so you
> only need to import from `react-router-dom` in your project.

([Source: GitHub](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4648#issuecomment-284479720))

Comment: but do you need to npm install both react-router and react-router-dom separately?

Comment: @joedotnot no. react-router-dom have everything from react-router. See example here. 
https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic

Answer (score 10):

Found this in the Github.

Note: This package provides the core routing functionality for React Router, but you might not want to install it directly. If you are writing an application that will run in the browser, you should instead install `react-router-dom`. Similarly, if you are writing a React Native application, you should instead install `react-router-native`. Both of those will install `react-router` as a dependency.

Source: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/packages/react-router