# ReactJS - issue about Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a component that imports a Router and it isn't working and there isn't any error message. The pages aren't appearing on the browser. It is a course s' app. Because of the fact that this course is a bit old, some things could be overpast. Here are the codes of my components:

```
import '../common/template/dependencies'
import React from 'react'    

import Routes from './Routes'

export default props => (
  <div className='wrapper'>   
    <div className='content-wrapper'>
     <Routes />
     </div>
  </div>
)
```

The component Routes.js that does the routing:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Router, Route , Redirect, hasHistory} from 'react-router'

import Dashboard from '../dashboard/Dashboard'
import BillingCycle from '../billingCycle/BillingCycle'

export default props => (
  <Router history={hasHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={Dashboard} />
    <Route path='/billingCycles' component={BillingCycle} />
    <Redirect from='*' to='/' />
  </Router>
)
```

When I comment this line of the component above, everything works well.

```
  {/*<Routes />*/}
```

Comment: what is Dashboard component have ?

Comment: This component has only a h1:  <h1>Dashboard</h1> because we are in the beginning of the construction of the app

Comment: did you try adding `exact` to your `/` path and putting it after `/billingCycles`?

Comment: Yes. I tried it now and it didn't work

Comment: Why are you not using `react-router-dom`?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684809/react-router-vs-react-router-dom-when-to-use-one-or-the-other

Comment: Because I'm following the course's steps. I will try to change it for react-router-dom. The course is a bit old

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Dashboard from './DashBoard';
import BillingCycle from './BillingCycle'

export default props => (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Dashboard}/>
            <Route exact path='/billingCycles' component={BillingCycle}/>
            <Redirect from='*' to='/'/>
        </Switch>
    </Router>

)
```

Check your code does hasHistory is available in new version react-router. 
    Also you should use react-router-dom.
    Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Use `react-router-dom`

Change your import in Route.js like this:

`import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'`