# issue with react-router BrowserRouter in react with typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, api, react-hooks

I have gone through several similar questions but could not find something that worked. I am trying to bring in BrowserRouter from react-router but it says:

Module '"../node_modules/@types/react-router"' has no exported member 'BrowserRouter'

as per another similar question on here, I did an npm install of @types/react and @types/react-router but saved as dev dependencies. they were already in my package.json but as regular dependencies. before this, they were giving a similar issue when doing import React from 'react'. It would say that those modules could not be found, same for router. then when i did the install, those errors went away but the BrowserRouter started showing this error. I did also try 'react-router-dom'.

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router';
import './App.css';

import Recipes from './components/Recipes';

const App: React.SFC = () => {

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <main>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Recipes} />
        </Switch>
      </main>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Just expecting for the error to not be present and to be able to regularly navigate. This is my first time really using typescript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) of React Router, `BrowserRouter` gets imported from 'react-router-dom', not 'react-router'.

Here is the example code given in the link above.

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

<BrowserRouter
  basename={optionalString}
  forceRefresh={optionalBool}
  getUserConfirmation={optionalFunc}
  keyLength={optionalNumber}
>
  <App/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42686239/11995384) is a SO question about the difference between `react-router` and `react-router-dom` and the accepted answer contains the following.

> react-router contains all the common components between react-router-dom and react-router-native. When should you use one over the other? If you're on the web then react-router-dom should have everything you need as it also exports the common components you'll need. If you're using React Native, react-router-native should have everything you need for the same reason. So you'll probably never have to import anything directly from react-router.

Comment: Thank you I was very confused since I did npm i of react-router not react-router-dom.

Answer (score 1):

> I did also try 'react-router-dom'.

It should work, e.g. this code

```js
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
```

works.

Both `react-dom` and `react-router-dom` packages should be installed. That means both can be found in the `dependencies` section of `package.json` file. Working sample project using Typescript can be found [here](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react/tree/master/client).

Comment: Hi thank you, yes i installed react-router not react-router-dom and didnt realize the mistake lol.