# Cannot read property 'history' of undefined (useHistory hook of React Router 5)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom, react-context

I am using the new useHistory hook of React Router, which came out a few weeks ago. My React-router version is 5.1.2. My React is at version 16.10.1. You can find my code at the bottom.

Yet when I import the new useHistory from react-router, I get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined`

which is caused by this line in React-router

```
function useHistory() {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
    !(typeof useContext === "function") ? process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" ? invariant(false, "You must use React >= 16.8 in order to use useHistory()") : invariant(false) : void 0;
  }

  return useContext(context).history; <---------------- ERROR IS ON THIS LINE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
}
```

Since it is related to useContext and perhaps a conflict with context is at fault, I tried completely removing all calls to useContext, creating the provider, etc. However, that did nothing. Tried with React v16.8; same thing.
I have no idea what could be causing this, as every other feature of React router works fine.

***Note that the same thing happens when calling the other React router hooks, such as useLocation or useParams.

Has anyone else encountered this? Any ideas to what may cause this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I found nothing on the web related to this issue.

```
import React, {useEffect, useContext} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Switch, useHistory } from 'react-router'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

import lazyLoader from 'CommonApp/components/misc/lazyLoader';
import {AppContext} from 'CommonApp/context/context';

export default function App(props) {
    const { i18n } = useTranslation();
    const { language } = useContext(AppContext);
    let history = useHistory();

    useEffect(() => {
        i18n.changeLanguage(language);
    }, []);

    return(
        <Router>
            <Route path="/">
                <div className={testClass}>HEADER</div>
            </Route>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

It's because the `react-router` context isn't set in that component. Since its the `<Router>` component that sets the context you could use `useHistory` in a sub-component, but not in that one.

Here is a very basic strategy for solving this issue:

```js
const AppWrapper = () => {
  return (
    <Router> // Set context
      <App /> // Now App has access to context
    </Router>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  let history = useHistory(); // Works!
...
// Render routes in this component
```

Then just be sure to use the "wrapper" component instead of `App` directly.

Comment: Thank you Brian. That was indeed the cause of the issue. :)

Comment: they should use just `useState` `useContext` just complicated thing

Comment: ...And the solution might be to lift the Router up.

Comment: Where to use the `AppWrapper ` ?

Answer (score 40):

Note to other people that run into this problem and already have wrapped the component with Router component. Make sure that Router and the useHistory hook are imported from the same package. The same error can be thrown when one of them are imported from react-router and the other one from react-router-dom and the package versions of those packages don't match. Don't use both of them, read about the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42686239/7584643).

Comment: zomg... thank you, thank you so much. If I could upvote this answer more than once, I would!

Comment: very precise and wise :)

Answer (score 10):

**useHistory** won't work in the component where you have your Routes because the context which is needed for **useHistory** is not yet set.

**useHistory** will work on any child component or components which you have declared in your **Router** but it won't work on **Router**'s parent component or **Router** component itself.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is:

in the Main (father) component

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

<BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>
```

in the child component (App)

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";


function App(props) {
    const { i18n } = useTranslation();
    const { language } = useContext(AppContext);
    let history = useHistory();

    useEffect(() => {
        i18n.changeLanguage(language);
    }, []);

    return(

            <Route path="/">
                <div className={testClass}>HEADER</div>
            </Route>

    )
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Comment: `withRouter()` doesn't seem to be needed. The example can be significantly reduced and improved (e.g. `onClick={history.replace(...)}`).

Answer (score 2):

I updated my `react-router-dom` from 5.0.0 to ^5.1.2 and it's been solved. You may notice that the `useHistory` is in a sub-component.

Answer (score 0):

Use BrowserRouter.

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
} from 'react-router-dom';
```

If you use Router, then you need to specify a history for it:

```
import {
  Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
} from 'react-router-dom';

// Ensure you destructure the createBrowserHistory object
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();
return (
  <Router history={history} >
    ...
  </Router>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In a short, you should move *const history = useHistory();* to your sub-component