# Redirect after Submit with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, routes, mern

I have a simple form that only required a username. I want to redirect my user after they submit their username but I don't really understand how to do that.

Here is my `class App`, in the render the Channels path works correctly.

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Channel from "./channels/Channel.js";
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import openSocket from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = openSocket('http://localhost:1270');

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: '' };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {    
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });  
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {

      const nom = this.state.value;
      alert(nom);
      event.preventDefault();

      this.props.history.push('/channels');

    }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
      <div>
        <p>Entrez un nom d'utilisateur :</p>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
          <input type="text"
              name="name"
              value={this.state.value} 
              onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <input type="submit" value="GO" />
        </form>  
        <Link to="/channels">Channels</Link>
      </div>
        <Route path="/channels" component={ Channel }>
          <Channel />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

However when I try to add a redirect to the Submit event I got that error

```
this.props.router is undefined
```

Comment: this.props.history.push("/channels")

Comment: @Antax I got this error `this.props.history is undefined`

Comment: can you paste in more code?

only the render and handleSubmit is not enough to help you right now

Comment: @Antax added all my code !

Comment: okay can you make a console.log(this.props) in handleSumbit - function

maybe your props are this.props.props

Comment: @Antax I get what appears to be an empty Object `Object {  }`, if I do `console.log(this.props.pros)` I get `undefined`

Comment: and what does this.props say?

Comment: @Antax Only the empty Object and nothing else

Comment: console.log(this.props). Do you see history?

Comment: okay pretty weird...

try this:
```
<form onSubmit={() => this.handleSubmit(e, this.props)} >
```

```  handleSubmit(event, props) {

      console.log(props)

    }
```

Comment: @zS1L3NT I don't see any history in my console.log

Comment: @Antax It changes my url to `http://localhost:3000/?name=k` but doesn't console.log anything

Comment: add event.preventDefault();

so it doesn't redirect, or have you preserved logs?

Comment: @Antax With `event.preventDefault()` I also get empty Object, I don't have any logs

Comment: Its really the same problem listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58220995/cannot-read-property-history-of-undefined-usehistory-hook-of-react-router-5/58221867#58221867). The `Router` sets the history value, so you can only use it in a sub component, You'll have to put the `Router` at a higher level to get it to work.

Comment: `props` don't magically appear. You either pass them to a component yourself, or a third party component does it for you. `Router` adds some props to each of it's child components (history, location, etc). But the parent component does not have access to these

Comment: @BrianThompson If I understand correctly I should put my form in a Sub component ?

Comment: If your form and submit function were in a sub component, I believe they should have access to the `history` prop.