# react-router-dom `history`: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom, browser-history

I have in my parent component `App.js` a `Header`  and a `Footer`.
I want to switch the components between the `Header` and `Footer` by clicking buttons inside the two of them.
Each time the `pageIndex` changed I want to replace to some other component.

I'm getting this error `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`
Why am I getting this error **and** is that a clean and proper whey to do it (with my `defaultRouter()` and `useMemo`) **?**

```js
 function App() {
      const [pageIndex, setPageIndex] = useState();
      const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);

      const history = useHistory();

       useEffect(() => {
         console.log(pageIndex, 'App');
       }, [pageIndex]);
    
    const defaultRouter = useMemo(() => {
     // Or -  `const DefaultRouter = useMemo(() =>` instead of `useEffect()`
    switch (pageIndex) {
      case 1:
        history.push({ pathname: '/search', state: searchResults });
        break;
      case 2:
        history.push('/cart');
        break;
      default:
        history.push('/');
        break;
    }
   }, [pageIndex]);

      return (
        <div className='App'>
          <Header/>
          <Home />
          {defaultRouter};  
          <Footer />  
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Route path='/'>
              <Home />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/search'>
              <Search
                searchResults={searchResults}
                setItemsAmount={setItemsAmount}
              />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/cart'>
              <Cart />
            </Route>
            <Route component={PageNotFound} />
          </BrowserRouter>
          ;
        </div>
      );
    }
```

#### Edit

As Shyam adviced in his answer below, I changed my `App.js` with `useCallback` **but `useCallback` just doesn't work**.

```js
  const defaultRouter = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(pageIndex, 'callBack');
    switch (pageIndex) {
      case 1:
        history.push({ pathname: '/search', state: searchResults });
        break;
      case 2:
        history.push('/cart');
        break;
      default:
        history.push('/');
        break;
    }
  }, [pageIndex]);
```

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

It's because the react-router context isn't set in that component.
Since its the  component that sets the context you could use useHistory in a sub-component, but not in that one.

Here is a very basic strategy for solving this issue:

```
const AppWrapper = () => {
  return (
    <Router> // Set context
      <App /> // Now App has access to context
    </Router>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  let history = useHistory(); // Works!
...
```

// Render routes in this component
Then just be sure to use the "wrapper" component instead of App directly.

Answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58221867/1723410

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
       <AppChildren />
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}     

function AppChildren() {
      const [pageIndex, setPageIndex] = useState();
      const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);

      const history = useHistory();

       useEffect(() => {
         console.log(pageIndex, 'App');
       }, [pageIndex]);
    
    const defaultRouter = useMemo(() => {
     // Or -  `const DefaultRouter = useMemo(() =>` instead of `useEffect()`
    switch (pageIndex) {
      case 1:
        history.push({ pathname: '/search', state: searchResults });
        break;
      case 2:
        history.push('/cart');
        break;
      default:
        history.push('/');
        break;
    }
   }, [pageIndex]);

      return (
        <div className='App'>
          <Header/>
          <Home />
          {defaultRouter};  
          <Footer />  
          <>
            <Route path='/'>
              <Home />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/search'>
              <Search
                searchResults={searchResults}
                setItemsAmount={setItemsAmount}
              />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/cart'>
              <Cart />
            </Route>
            <Route component={PageNotFound} />
          </>
        </div>
      );
}
```

Comment: 1) Should `AppWrapper` be in a different jsx file and be exported ? 2) My now `useCallback ` don't work when updating `pageIndex` in the `Header` component.

Comment: I tried it, it just doesn't work,  nor with `useCallback`, `useMemo` or `useEffect`

Comment: How/where to use the `AppWrapper` ?  I tried in index.js instead of `<App/>` but it gives an error - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined`

Comment: so here your BrowserRouter must be in parent component. I updated my answer above