# UseHistory Hook Not workin fine?

Tags: reactjs

*the error*

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')**

**My code**

```
import React from "react";

import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
const test = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  function buttonPressed() {
    history.push("/sus");
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => buttonPressed()}>Brn</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default test ;
```

**PLEASE HELP ME**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot read property 'history' of undefined (useHistory hook of React Router 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58220995/cannot-read-property-history-of-undefined-usehistory-hook-of-react-router-5)

Comment: *All React component names must start with a capital letter*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your router is configured properly to handle a push to route "/sus".

By the way, you can just call the onClick handler with

```
<button onClick={buttonPressed}>Btn</button>
```

Comment: Thanks i did not set up a router my fault ..

Comment: No problem! Glad you sorted it out, do you mind accepting my answer?