# useHistory() route state is Undefined in Typescript React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am passing table row data data object as a state in a route params i.e using useHistory react-router-dom.While receiving in the next screen as a props, for the first time i am getting it and immediately it becomes undefined.So can anyone please tell me why is this happening?

```
const onClickEntityName = (values: any) => {
navigate.push({ pathname: 'url here', state: values });
```

};

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58220995/cannot-read-property-history-of-undefined-usehistory-hook-of-react-router-5 You can check this

Comment: This is a different Question!