# Redirect to another page after login without page refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I am making a login page, I want when the person has successfully logged in to redirect them to another page, and I tried to do it with the reaction path but it doesn't work for me, so I would like you to recommend it to me. a library to be able to redirect to another route, if anyone knows any please help me, by the way it is a react project

Comment: I think you should use [`react-router`](https://reactrouter.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ***react-router*** plugin. Here is the link` https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Also npm link https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router

This is the best routing package for **React.js**.

Read the documentation, everything is explained in detail there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Router Manager? If not and your are working with React for the web, I highly recommend you to use react-router-dom because is an improve of react-router, this package export components ready to use, like  or  an so on.

I leave you this link where this topic in [react-router-vs-react-router-dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684809/react-router-vs-react-router-dom-when-to-use-one-or-the-other#:%7E:text=In%20v4%2C%20react%2Drouter%20exports,interacts%20with%20the%20browser%27s%20window.)

And off course, the package documentation/github: [react-router-dom-github](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-dom)

I hope I have been helpful.