# React Router: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentLocation' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

I am new to React overall and very new to React Router. I am building an app in which a list of reviews is displayed and when a user clicks a review card, they are redirected to a page that displays that card's details. I have the majority of the logic coded, but I am struggling with implementing React router. Here are my components so far.

```
import React from 'react';
import  ReviewCollection  from './components/ReviewCollection';
import  ReviewCard  from './components/ReviewCard';
import { Route, Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

class App extends React. Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Router >
         <Router history={browserHistory} />
         <ReviewCollection />
          <Route path={"/details"} component={ReviewCard} />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import ReviewCard from './ReviewCard';
import { reviews } from '../data';
import {reactLocalStorage} from 'reactjs-localstorage';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

class ReviewCollection extends React.Component {

    goToDetails = (review) => {
        reactLocalStorage.set('selectedReview', review);
       browserHistory.push('/details');
      };

      render() {
          return (
                <div className='card-collection'>
                    {reviews
                    .filter((review, idx) => idx < 24)
                    .map((review) => (
                     <div onClick={() => this.goToDetails(review)}>
                     <ReviewCard key={review.id} review={review} />
                      </div>
                    ))}
            </div>
          )
      }
}

export default ReviewCollection;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { reviews } from '../data';
import StarRatings from 'react-star-ratings';
import './Review.css';  

 const ReviewCard= ({ review }) => {
  return (  
    <div class="card-deck">
      {reviews.map((review) => {
        return (
         <div class="card">
          <div key={review.id}>
            <h4 class="card-title">{review.place}</h4>
            <StarRatings
                rating={review.rating}
                starRatedColor="gold" 
                starDimension="20px"
                />
            <div class="card-body">{review.content}</div>
            <div class="card-footer">{review.author} - {review.published_at}</div> 
            
      </div>
      </div>
        );
      })}
      </div> 
          );
      };
  
export default ReviewCard;
```

I am not confident as to whether or not I am headed in the right direction with how my routes are written overall, and in the browser, I am getting this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentLocation' of undefined" Can somebody please help me identify the problem? Thanks

**Edit #1**
Thanks for the advice guys. Here is my App.js component now that I have started to implement react-router-dom instead of react router:

```
import React from 'react';
import  ReviewCollection  from './components/ReviewCollection';
import  ReviewCard  from './components/ReviewCard';
import { BrowserRouter, Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import history from './history';


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter >
         <Router history={history} />
         <ReviewCollection />
          <Route path={"/details"} component={ReviewCard} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

But I am still confused as to how I should use browserHistory now in my ReviewCollection.js file. That has not changed and is still using the code `browserHistory.push('/details');`

Comment: Have you tried BrowserRouter ?

import {BrowserRouter }  from 'react-router';

then <BrowserRouter>...</BrowserRouter>

Comment: yes I did, weirdly I still get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use `react-router-dom` instead of `react-router`.Becuase `react-router-dom`  exports dom aware components most interestingly `browser.history`.

Check this for more info - [react-router vs react-router-dom, when to use one or the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684809/react-router-vs-react-router-dom-when-to-use-one-or-the-other)

Since you're using `browserHistory.push()`, better use `withRouter` HOC to do a redirection to the relevant page you want.

Check this for more info on that - [How to push to History in React Router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4)

Based on OP's suggestions, I believe it's essential to have 2 different paths for home page of the reviews and details page for a particular review (once user clicks). Therefore, using BrowserRouter, it is possible to create routings for both pages. Home page contains `ReviewCollection` which should render array of `ReviewHeader` components.
In review page, for a particular review, it should render `ReviewDetails` but not the `ReviewHeader` which should be kept separated, otherwise it will create an issue of using same component in 2 different places as you've encountered.

As I told earilier, in order to do a redirection, use `withRouter` HOC instead of `BrowserHistory`. Since it's an HOC, you need to wrap the component to use the history object extracted as a prop.

Use the following code-snippets as supprotive material for configuring `BrowserRouter` and `withRouter` HOC.

And check this to get more info on react-router: https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReviewCollection from "./ReviewCollection";
import ReviewCardDetails from "./ReviewCardDetails";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Route exact path="/" component={ReviewCollection} />
        <Route exact path="/details" component={ReviewCardDetails} />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In **App** module, I've given exact as a flag to `Route` component in order to keep our custom component mounting exactly for the given path. Otherwise `ReviewCollection` component will be kept intact even in `/details` route.

**ReviewCollection**

```
import React from "react";
import ReviewCardHeader from "./ReviewCardHeader";
import { reactLocalStorage } from "reactjs-localstorage";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const reviews = [
  {
    id: 1,
    place: "title 1",
    rating: 10,
    content: "content 1",
    author: "author 1",
    published_at: "published_at 1",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    place: "title 2",
    rating: 12,
    content: "content 2",
    author: "author 2",
    published_at: "published_at 2",
  },
];
class ReviewCollection extends React.Component {
  goToDetails = (review) => {
    reactLocalStorage.set("selectedReview", review);
    this.props.history.push({ pathname: "/details", state: { review } });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card-collection">
        {reviews
          .filter((review, idx) => idx < 24)
          .map((review) => (
            <div onClick={() => this.goToDetails(review)}>
              <ReviewCardHeader key={review.id} review={review} />
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(ReviewCollection);
```

**ReviewCardHeader**

```
import React from "react";
import StarRatings from "react-star-ratings";

const ReviewCardHeader = ({ review }) => {
  return (
    <div key={review.id} className="card-deck">
      <div className="card">
        <div>
          <h4 className="card-title">{review.place}</h4>
          <StarRatings
            rating={review.rating}
            starRatedColor="gold"
            starDimension="20px"
          />
          <div className="card-body">{review.content}</div>
          <div className="card-footer">
            {review.author} - {review.published_at}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ReviewCardHeader;
```

**ReviewCardDetails**

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import StarRatings from "react-star-ratings";

const ReviewCardDetails = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { review } = location?.state; // ? - optional chaining

  console.log("history location details: ", location);
  return (
    <div key={review.id} className="card-deck">
      <div className="card">
        <div>
          <h4 className="card-title">{review.place}</h4>
          <StarRatings
            rating={review.rating}
            starRatedColor="gold"
            starDimension="20px"
          />
          <div className="card-body">{review.content}</div>
          <div className="card-footer">
            {review.author} - {review.published_at}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ReviewCardDetails;
```

**Home Page View**

[image]

**Details Page View**

[image]

Hope this would be helpful to solve your issue. And make sure to have different details for header and details component since header means a summary of a particular review.

Comment: Hi there thanks for your help! If you would not mind checking my edit on my post, I am still a bit stuck. I read through the documentation you sent me and still do not quite understand how to use the browserHistory.push() here. thank you for your help!

Comment: Have a small issue, why do you have `reviews.map()` in **ReviewCard** component, which actually needs to show the view relevant to a particular review instead of using it for all the reviews. And also, since **review** object is passed from parent component to ReviewCard, it shows a lint error: `'review' is already declared in the upper scope`. Therefore, I believe it should also need to be corrected.

Comment: And also use `className` instead of using `class` for JSX elements

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much for all of your help! I just saw your code, thank you!! I really appreciate this!

Comment: Use it as a supportive material to modify your implementation and please kindly accept the answer if it's perfectly appropriate as a solution for your issue by clicking on tick button to the left corner of the answer.